# Convert column containing times to Date

Tags: r, date

I got a column containing times in the format 20:41, 00:01, 23:59. I am trying to convert this column to the Date type however my code produces all NA values.

This is the code I am using to convert:

```
my_df$times<- as.Date(my_df$times, "%h:%m")
```

What is causing this?

Comment: @RonakShah what do you mean by times shared?

Comment: @RonakShah after reading https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html I expected to get a fragment of a date back (the time 20:41 for example). It could be that I missed something and storing only the hours and minutes is not possible?

Comment: @RonakShah how would I not loose the hours and minutes parts? I found out I indeed get  the current date saved when using H and M instead of h and m. So the only issue left now is not loosing that hour and time part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as.POSIXct` to convert hour-minute to date-time values.

```
x <- c('20:41', '00:01', '23:59')
as.POSIXct(x, format = '%H:%M', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2020-10-06 20:41:00 UTC" "2020-10-06 00:01:00 UTC" "2020-10-06 23:59:00 UTC"
#Or with strptime
#strptime(x, format = '%H:%M', tz = 'UTC')
```

If we want to include dates as separate vector we can use `paste` to combine  date and time together and then use `as.POSIXct` :

```
x <- c('20:41', '00:01', '23:59')
y <- c('2020-01-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-09-06')

as.POSIXct(paste(y, x), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2020-01-02 20:41:00 UTC" "2020-03-03 00:01:00 UTC" "2020-09-06 23:59:00 UTC"
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. Would it be possible to use a second vector to specify the date so it does not insert today's date?

Comment: See updated answer if that is what you meant.

Comment: Your my hero for the day.